# How to use "And" and "Or" keywords together in a same "If" statement

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

I'm trying to use `And` and `Or`keywords on a single If statement in my VB Script, which I use with VLC Media Player to stream using command line.
I tried it like:

```
If (CurrentEP >= 2) And (CStr(TSNStr) = CStr(PTSNStr)) And (((CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr)) <= 5) Or ((CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr)) >= -5)) Then
```

I tried putting parentheses for the whole `If` statement, but it did nothing.

```
If ((CurrentEP >= 2) And (CStr(TSNStr) = CStr(PTSNStr)) And (((CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr)) <= 5) Or ((CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr)) >= -5))) Then
```

When I execute my script, only below two conditions seems to work.

```
1.If ((CurrentEP >= 2) Then '<< FIRST CONDITION

2.If (CStr(TSNStr) = CStr(PTSNStr)) Then '<< SECOND CONDITION
```

The third condition

`(((CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr)) <= 5) Or ((CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr)) >= -5)))`

always evaluates to false, which should check if difference of `TSSEPStr` and `PTSSEPStr` is either less than / equal to 5 or greater than / equal to -5.

I want to know if is it possible to use an `Or` keyword in a statement that is also used with multiple other `And` keywords in VB Script.

Comment: With valid values in the variables I don't see how your *third condition* could be anything but always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*With the help of @GaryEvans's answer,* I found that this line always evaluated to false because usage of too many parentheses.

I just made an small change and the following line worked as I expected:

```
If (CurrentEP >= 2) And (CStr(TSNStr) = CStr(PTSNStr)) And (CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr) <= 5) And (CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr) >= -5) Then
```

And made it more shorter and clearer:

```
If (CurrentEP >= 2) And (CStr(TSNStr) = CStr(PTSNStr)) And (CInt(TSSEPStr - PTSSEPStr) <= 5) And (CInt(TSSEPStr - PTSSEPStr) >= -5) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, the devil is in the detail, it is all about think of all possible paths and paying close attention to the bracketing which determines the order of evaluation (which from looking at your code, you are well aware of).

The deepest bracketed evaluations are performed first then the next level up until you reach the top. For example (and you can try this in Excel): -

```
5 / 4 * 3 / 2      = 1.875
5 / (4 * 3) / 2    = 0.208333333
```

The evaluations are:-

```
1.25 * 3 / 2
3.75 / 2
1.875
```

and

```
5 / 12 / 2
0.416666667 / 2
0.208333333
```

There is an arithmetic [order of precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/operator-precedence) that also comes into play here that you *may* want to read up on.

Also, (and you probably know this too) *all* elements in an `AND` evaluation must be `True` for the result to be `True`. *Any* elements in an `OR` evaluation that are `True` will result in a `True`.

`True` `AND` `True` `AND` `True` = `True`

`True` `AND` `True` `AND` `False` = `False`

`True` `OR` `True` `OR` `True` = `True`

`True` `OR` `True` `OR` `False` = `True`

You can then also add parenthesis to adjust the order evaluation: -

`True` `AND` (`True` `AND` `True`) = `True`

`True` `AND` (`True` `OR` `False`) = `True`

`False` `OR` (`False` `AND` `True`) = `False`

To your issue, I think you have your greater than and less than mixed up, there was slightly to much bracketing as well but it should have evaluated still.

1 > 2 = `False`

2 > 1 = `True`

2 > 2 = `False`

1 < 2 = `True`

2 < 1 = `False`

2 < 2 = `False`

Lets call `CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr)` `i`: -

```
i = 0
(i >= 5) Or (i <= -5) = (False) Or (False) = False
```

0 is not greater than or equal to 5, 0 is not less than or equal to -5

```
i = 10
(i >= 5) Or (i <= -5) = (True) Or (False) = True
```

10 is greater than or equal to 5, 10 is not less than or equal to -5

This is saying it must be **out of** the range of -5 to 5. if we flip the greater than/less than operators it says that is must be **in** the range of -5 to 5, also we need to change `Or` to `And`.

```
i = 0
(i <= 5) And (i >= -5) = (True) And (True) = True
```

0 is less than or equal to 5, 0 is greater than or equal to -5

```
i = 10
(i <= 5) And (i >= -5) = (False) And (True) = False
```

10 is not less than or equal to 5, 10 is greater than or equal to -5

```
If (CurrentEP >= 2) And (CStr(TSNStr) = CStr(PTSNStr)) And (CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr) >= 5) And (CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr) <= -5) Then
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped me a lot, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Having many conditions always makes the evaluation tricky because of Precedence and Order of Evaluation. You might want to review those rules in relation to vb-script. The solution is usually parentheses like you attempted but I suspect you need one more pair around the first two conditions like:

```
If (((CurrentEP >= 2) And (CStr(TSNStr) = CStr(PTSNStr))) And (((CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr)) <= 5) Or ((CInt(TSSEPStr) - CInt(PTSSEPStr)) >= -5))) Then
```